# Compare multiple file suffixes containing date & time and do action on most recent

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, filenames

I have multiple files in a directory that follow the below pattern.
`logA.log.$todayDate.$timeCreated`
`logA.log.07222020.084355`
I want to compare the **$timeCreated** part of all the files in the directory created on todays date to obtain the latest version of the log file and then perform actions on that file once it is obtained.
Does anyone know the best way that I can do this?

Comment: Using YMD instead of MDY has the advantage of not only being standard, but also sortable.

Comment: Please add your own attempts to the question. A minimal example, with a list of file names and the one that should be selected, is also useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`some_command_that_takes_this_file_as_argument $(find . -iname "logA.log.$(date +%m%d%Y).[0-9]*" 2> /dev/null | sort -n | tail -1)` should do the trick

**Edit**: If you just want to use the newest logfile you could make it even easier:
`some_command_that_takes_this_file_as_argument $(ls -rt | grep ^logA.log. | tail -1)`

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: `sort -n` doesn't do what you think it does here. `sort -n` interprets the lines as numbers and sorts based on those numbers. Here, all lines will be interpreted as `0` as they start with `./` which is not a number. The only reason it works is that in case of tie, `sort` resorts to a lexical comparison of the full line.  Note that `find` will recurse into directories to find the files, and if it finds files in more than one directory, it will likely not work as the directory part will be taken into account in that lexical sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
set -- logA.log."$(date +%m%d%Y)".*
eval "latest=\${$#}"
```

(or `shift "$(($# - 1))"; latest=$1` if you have religious objections to using `eval`, though that particular use of `eval` is perfectly safe).

As glob expansions are sorted lexically, given your `HHMMSS` format, the last one in that list will be the latest one.

With `zsh`:

```
(){latest=$argv[-1];} logA.log.${(%):-%D{%m%d%Y}}.*
```

Or:

```
(){latest=$1;} logA.log.${(%):-%D{%m%d%Y}}.*([-1])
```

`${(%):-%D{%m%d%Y}}` uses the `%` parameter expansion flag to expands `%D{%m%d%Y}` as prompt expansion. You could of course replace it with `"$(date +%m%d%Y)"` to make it more legible though that would involve forking an extra process and executing a separate utility.

Alternatively you could use `zsh`'s builtin `strftime` command (in the `zsh/datetime` module) as `strftime -s today %m%d%Y` to fill the `$today` variable with that timestamp.

Comment: Brilliant. And this eval is totally safe as `$#` is just a number.